# Scrolling page action without click function in html/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am using this code to scroll the page after clicking a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 8000);
  });
});
```

But I want to make it work without clicking any button. When the page loads, it should scroll. I used this code and it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 8000);
});
```

Comment: see [infinitescroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll)

Comment: hope u putting this code `$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
}, 8000);` in document.ready

Comment: Yes @Cyril. All there.

Comment: `$($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top` sure this is 0 that is why its not scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally am not a big fan of using jQuery's animate function, so i implemented my own. You can change the speed of it by increasing or decreasing the time of the setTimeout function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pixels = $('a').position();
    Scroll(pixels.top);
});

function Scroll(pixels) {
    if( pixels > 0){
        window.scrollBy(0,1);
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            Scroll(pixels-1); 
        },1);
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout)
        return;
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the fiddle that i made to demonstrate what I think you are trying to do.
Let me know if this helps!

https://jsfiddle.net/ogb4t33q/

Answer (score 1):

In this block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 8000);
});
```

`this` will refer to document. That was OK in the other version of your function, because `this` referred to an `<a>` element with `href`. That allowed `$($.attr(this, 'href'))` to find an element and complete the logic to scroll there.

You'll either need to define exactly the element you want to scroll to like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#scrollToThisEl').offset().top
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:3000px;background:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,#606dbc,#606dbc 50px,#465298 50px,#465298 100px);"></div>
<div id="scrollToThisEl">Scroll here</div>
<div style="height:3000px;"></div>
```

Or work with [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to read the `#...` value from the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
  }, 3000);
});
```