# How can we manually fire scroll-up & scroll-down events

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is it possible to fire scroll-up & scroll-down event using jquery's trigger method like we can do for click`$(".fa.fa-plus-square.zoom").trigger("click");` same way can we do it for scroll on any DOM element?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152007/scrolling-page-action-without-click-function-in-html-js

Comment: @Cyril  Its not about page scroll !! I'm using scroll for zooming into some charts i.e. on DOM elements click clicking on some button it will scroll-in.

Comment: you can trigger a scroll event https://jsfiddle.net/pzzctkv8/

Comment: thanks but I want to fire scroll-up/ scroll-down based on some button click and it won't scroll the page. @madalinivascu

Comment: If you want to zoom something in/out, then why not trigger _that_ functionality directly, why a detour via artificially triggered scroll events …?

Comment: @GovindMantri But _madalin ivascu_'s suggestion does exactly that...

Comment: @GovindMantri use the Chart systems' methods for zooming in/out and call those from your click events.

Comment: @CBroe my current functionality is working fine with mouse scroll-in/out but what about the same chart on touch device or to have step by step (+1 level) zoom as with scroll user don't know how much they did. For that I made zoom-in/out button and clicking on those I want to fire scroll event as my charts is not allowing me to directly call method to zoom on click.

Comment: @LGSon yes but it is just scroll doesn't determine weather its in/out. It is good for doing simple scroll events.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli already using it for with scroll events but for buttons as I mentioned in one of the answer above I need to fire this artificial event.

Comment: You will have to show us you current setup of the code etc for comments on such specific case. A minimal working example would be the best.